# ¿Cómo validar que en un datetimepicker no se coja una fecha y hora anterior

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito saber cómo hacer para que el datetimepicker solo me deje escoger una fecha y una hora posterior a la del momento. Es decir, que no me deje escoger ni fechas ni horas pasadas.
Gracias!

```js
 <script>
        $("#datetimepicker2").datetimepicker();
    </script>
```

```html
<section class="contenedor4">
    
                <p class="rojo planes"> Reprogramar agenda</p>
                <br>
                                    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>

            
  </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con `$("#datetimepicker2").datetimepicker({minDate: tu_fecha});`

`tu_fecha` puede tener varios formatos, puedes poner un valor numérico (0 hoy, 1 mañana, -1 ayer, etc), un string en el mismo formato que obtienes la fecha (puedes cambiarlo con la propiedad `dateFormat`), o un objeto del tipo Date

Comment: ¿En qué formato se debe proporcionar `tu_fecha`?

Comment: @Triby tienes varias opciones, puedes poner un valor numérico (0 hoy, 1 mañana, -1 ayer, etc), un string en el mismo formato que obtienes la fecha (puedes cambiarlo con la propiedad `dateFormat`, o un objeto del tipo Date

Comment: Lo ideal es que en tu respuesta proporciones esa información para que realmente le sea de utilidad a AP (autor de la pregunta).

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que entiendo, estás utilizando la librería [Jquery.datetimePicker](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#Inline)

En la [documentación](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#mindate) puedes ver el ejemplo de `minDate` que es el parámetro a modificar.

Te he incluido una parte que he obtenido de una [respuesta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only) donde ya seleccionan fechas, para que veas cómo se maneja el objeto `Date` para poder sumar o restar días o meses a tu antojo.

> Como verás, siempre pone como fecha mínima 10 días después de hoy, y
>   fecha máxima 100 días después de hoy. Además, como fecha seleccionada
>   por defecto, selecciona hoy+10 días.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({

            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            showButtonPanel: true,
            showMonthAfterYear: true,
            showWeek: true,
            showAnim: "drop",
            constrainInput: true,
            minDate: new Date((new Date().getFullYear()), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate()+10), //10 dias despues es la fecha minima
            maxDate: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate() + 100), //100 dias despues es la fecha minima
            defaultDate: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate()+10), //la fecha por defecto, la fecha mínima

  });
  
  
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>


<p class = "rojo planes" > Reprogramar agenda </p>
<br>
<input type = "text"  class="datetimepicker" id="datetimepicker2" >
```